# How does Qt work (exactly)?

Tags: python, qt

When you write an application using Qt, can it just be run right away in different operating systems? And (correct me if I'm wrong) you don't need to have Qt already installed in all of the different platforms where you want to execute your application?

How exactly does this work? Does Qt compile to the desired platform, or does it bundle some "dlls" (libs), or how does it do it? Is it different from programming a Java application,  that runs cross-platform.

If you use Python to write a Qt application with Python bindings, does your end user need to have Python installed?

Comment: Both of the current answers neglected to provide this link so I will:
http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/deployment.html It details how to deploy (and some compile settings you may need) on all the platforms.  But it still does require compiling on every platform you want to run it on.

Comment: You're commenting about py2exe, does something similar exist for Linux?

Comment: @David: I meant the libraries (which do need to be compiled or downloaded for each platform), but yes you are correct :)

Comment: David: I thought Python was byte-compiled.  That's why it makes these *.pyc files, and I can delete the *.py files and it still runs, no?  It just doesn't happen to require me to invoke the compiler explicitly like Java does.

Comment: David: I don't know what you mean by "associated with the `pyc` filetype" -- Python simply doesn't bother looking for *.py if *.pyc is present.  And the distinction sounds like purely a matter of vocabulary: Java's runtime is called a "VM", while Python's runtime is called an "interpreter", even though they both are executing bytecodes.  It's no wonder people are confused, when our terminology is based more on historical accident than what things do today.  :-)

Comment: David: The part that says "there are virtual machines for Java, Python, ...", a little after the part that says "virtual machine (i.e., interpreter)"?  :-)  I've written compilers and interpreters and bytecode generators and I still can't identify a hard line between them all.

Comment: Could someone with the required rep please edit this? For some reason, every time I read it, in my head it has an Indian accent and makes my head hurt.

Comment: I updated the english usage. :-)

Comment: @Warren P: Thanks, english isn't my native language and I wrote the post really fast. It is indeed much better after your editions. (And @Evan Plaice, I'm not "Indian", and doing this kind of comment doesn't help anything either. Prejudice against different cultures/countries is not a good thing. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

PyQT [and its open source cousin PySide] are a great cross-platform QT binding for python, but it is not a magic solution for shipping your application for all platforms without doing any packaging/installer maintenance. I think maybe you might be expecting some magic.

QT is a cross-platform library written in C++.  That means, you can write your C++ or Python (or other language with bindings) code once,  and create a "window" (a form, a dialog box, something on the screen) and populate it with controls (buttons, and all that) and not have to deal with the platform differences in how buttons are made in Windows, Linux, and on Mac OS X.

Because it is a library, it can be packaged in multiple ways. It can be "statically linked" (built into your executable/binary/app) or "dynamically linked" (known as a DLL in windows, a shared library or on unix/linux or as a framework, in mac os x). It is not always "installed" on a computer, unless it is a shared library.

Even when it is "installed" onto a computer, multiple versions might exist on that computer, and so it is not proper to think of it as being an extension to your computer, but rather an extension to an application (a program) on your computer.

If you use Python bindings for QT, then your installation package for your application needs to include the QT binding's binary files (python extensions), the basic Python runtime environment including the Python executable and basic libraries, and your program's source code. It is possible to package most of this up into a single "bundle". On Mac OS X, for instance, all this can easily be put into a an ".app" bundle, and on Windows, and Linux, I believe there are packaging and installation tools that can help you do this easily.

Even though you will only need to write the user interface code for your application once, you will not magically get the ability to ship an application on all three primary platforms at once, without doing at least the building of the installer or packaging, separately for each platform.  Users expect to download a setup/install package for Windows or Mac OS X, and perhaps for Unix/Linux it depends further on which distribution you install.

[Update thanks to AdamW for this nokia link providing deployment information](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/deployment.html)

Comment: Warren, thanks for a clarifying answer in so many levels. I'm asking this question because I was thinking of a Python app, and thought about going cross-platform, but I'm new to Desktop programming (I develop mainly web). I came with GTK, Qt and Appcelerator and I was trying to really understand which of these solutions would be ideal for me based in what they exatcly offer.

Comment: Python gives you a huge benefit in language (easy to learn, and powerful) but one area of Python that is hugely fragmented is the "Which GUI?" question.  You should probably consider Python Bindings for WxWidgets as well.  Some people say that if the TkInter (tcl/tk) gui (which I think is crap) hadn't shipped first, that WxPython would have been the default Python GUI.  It also handles Windows, Mac, and Linux, and has a large active community.

Comment: @Somebody if you're looking for a markup file that is cross-platform language-agnostic like HTML/CSS for QT be sure to check out QML.

Comment: Is QML the XAML equivalent for QT?

Answer (score 15):

Qt (ideally) provides source compatibility, not binary compatibility.  You still have to compile the application separately for each platform, and use the appropriate dynamic Qt libraries (which also need to be compiled separately, and have some platform-specific code).

For your final question, the user would need Python, the Qt libraries, and the binding library (e.g. pyqt), but there are various ways to bundle these.

Comment: So, without bundling them, I would have a (just an example) a 4mb file to install, and bundling everything something like 40mb - like bundling Java itself if it were Java. Am i right?

Comment: Don't know about the exact numbers, but that's basically right.  If you know the user already has the right Qt dynamic libraries, you don't have to bundle them.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is your definition of "installed". For Qt to work, the executable just has to have access to the proper libraries.

Of course that for each platform a different executable and libraries have to be produced (see [Qt docs](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/deployment.html)).

About Python, if you are to run a Python executable you have to have it installed (in a more traditional kind of way). Unless you are running with py2exe in Windows, for instance.

Comment: So, does Qt handles everything for me for these libraries, for each plataform I deploy an application? I create a cross-plataform one, and  want to deploy it on Linux and Windows, does it bundle these libs in a a transparent way?

Comment: No, Qt just provides a means to generate from the same source, different binaries that will run in different platforms. You'd still have to provide different binaries/installers for each platform. You could have a single installer to detect platform and install the proper version, but I fail to see any benefit to that approach.

Comment: My bad, I know it's going to create different binaries. I just want to know if Qt creates them for me.

Comment: @Somebody still uses you MS-DOS - Qt doesn't create the other binaries for you (although it does come with a multi-platform replacement for make) it simply has a set of function calls to do all the platform specific stuff (like gui/filesystem) that are the same on all platforms.  Then you simply bundle the Qt libraries for the platform you are targetting,